# Finding the supremum and infimum of a specified set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$A=\left\{\displaystyle \sqrt[n]{a} \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}, \ a>0$$

Hi, I've been stuck on this for a few hours now. I need to find sup(A) and inf(A) of this set. If anyone can provide a proof that would be a huge help! thanks.

Comment: Hint: consider the three cases $a<1,a=1,a>1$ separately.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt[n]{a}=a^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Comment: If you've spent a long time on this exercise and gotten nowhere, it is time to change your approach to solving this problem. Try writing out the definitions of $\sup$ and $\inf$; how are they different from just finding the largest and smallest number in a set?

Answer (score 1):

If $a=1$ it's easy.

If $a>1$ then the sequence $\root n \of {a}$ is decreasing and converges to $1$, so $\sup A=a$ and $\inf A=1$.

If $a<1$ its dually similar to the case $a>1$.